# tomcat server giving issues to run the application

Tags: netbeans, tomcat6

I am trying to run the application. just i installed the tomcat and netBeans.
    It is giving following error. if i try to give build alone,,, build is successful. but i am unable to deploy in server ...

```
Created dir: D:\Test\build\generated\src
Created dir: D:\Test\build\generated\classes
Compiling 1 source file to D:\Test\build\generated\classes
Undeploying ...
undeploy?path=/excelRD
OK - Undeployed application at context path /excelRD
In-place deployment at D:\Test\build\web
D:\Test\build\web\META-INF\context.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
D:\Test\nbproject\build-impl.xml:686: The module has not been deployed.
```

Please do needful

Answer (score 1):

The error message seems clear you need a file `context.xml` in your project.
In a regular apache project created with Netbeans, you have in the directory `Web Pages` an other directory names `META-INF` and in this directory the file `context.xml`. 
Try to respect this architecture. The minimal `context.xml` contant is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/excelRD"/>
```

Comment: Appearently NetBeans creates by itself, using GIT I reverted local changes (my colleagues dont use NetBeans) and the file was gone. Restarting NB + rebuilding helped me therefore.

Answer (score 0):

He may also be seeing an issues I've seen on NetBeans for years.  You have a perfectly valid context.xml file that can't be found by NetBeans during deployment.  If you open the file, touch it in anyway (type in a character, delete that character, then save), the problem goes away.  I've had this happen so many times that I've gotten in the habit of always touching the context.xml file before I deploy.